# Labelling issue after using gap.plot to create an axis break

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

I've been struggling to get a plot that shows my data accurately, and spent a while getting gap.plot up and running. After doing so, I have an issue with labelling the points.

Just plotting my data ends up with this:

[Plot of abundance data, basically two different tiers of data at ~38,000, and between 1 - 50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxRjX.png)

As you can see, that doesn't clearly show either the top or the bottom sections of my plots well enough to distinguish anything.

Using gap plot, I managed to get:

[gap.plot of abundance data, 100 - 37000 missed, labels only appearing on the lower tier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lleXo.png)

The code for my two plots is pretty simple:

```
plot(counts.abund1,pch=".",main= "Repeat 1")
text(counts.abund1, labels=row.names(counts.abund1), cex= 1.5)

gap.plot(counts.abund1[,1],counts.abund1[,2],gap=c(100,38000),gap.axis="y",xlim=c(0,60),ylim=c(0,39000))
text(counts.abund1, labels=row.names(counts.abund1), cex= 1.5)
```

But I don't know why/can't figure out why the labels (which are just the letters that the points denote) are not being applied the same in the two plots.

I'm kind of out of my depth trying this bit, very little idea how to plot things like this nicely, never had data like it when learning.

The data this comes from is originally a large (10,000 x 10,000 matrix) that contains a random assortment of letters a to z, then has replacements and "speciation" or "immigration" which results in the first lot of letters at ~38,000, and the second lot normally below 50.

The code I run after getting that matrix to get the rank abundance is:

```
##Abundance 1
counts1 <- as.data.frame(as.list(table(neutral.v1)))
counts.abund1<-rankabundance(counts1)
```

With neutral.v1 being the matrix.

The data frame for counts.abund1 looks like (extremely poorly formatted, sorry):

```
rank    abundance   proportion  plower  pupper  accumfreq   logabun rankfreq    

a   1   38795   3.9 NaN NaN 3.9 4.6 1.9
x   2   38759   3.9 NaN NaN 7.8 4.6 3.8
j   3   38649   3.9 NaN NaN 11.6    4.6 5.7
m   4   38639   3.9 NaN NaN 15.5    4.6 7.5
```

and continues for all the variables. I only use Rank and Abundance right now, with the a,x,j,m just the variable that applies to, and what I want to use as the labels on the plot.

Any advice would be really appreciated. I can't really shorten the code too much or provide the matrix because the type of data is quite specific, as are the quantities in a sense.

As I mentioned, I've been using gap.plot to just create a break in the axis, but if there are better solutions to plotting this type of data I'd be absolutely all ears.

Really sorry that this is a mess of a question, bit frazzled on the whole thing right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gap.plot()` doesn't draw two plots but one plot by decreasing upper section's value, drawing additional box and rewriting axis tick labels. So, the upper region's y-coordinate is neither equivalent to original value nor axis tick labels. The real y-coordinate in upper region is `"original value" - diff(gap)`.

```
gap.plot(counts.abund1[,1], counts.abund1[,2], gap=c(100,38000), gap.axis="y", 
         xlim=c(0,60), ylim=c(0,39000))
text(counts.abund1, labels=row.names(counts.abund1), cex= 1.5)
text(counts.abund1[,1], counts.abund1[,2] - diff(c(100, 38000)), labels=row.names(counts.abund1), cex=1.5)

# the example data I used
set.seed(1)
counts.abund1 <- data.frame(rank = 1:50, 
                            abundance = c(rnorm(25, 38500, 100), rnorm(25, 30, 20)))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Had no idea. Thanks very much.